# how to call a specific dotnet core version

Tags: .net-core

I have installed two dotnet core versions i.e. 2.2 & 3.0 Preview.

```
2.2.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview-010184 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

I need to make a call in the command prompt to a specific dotnet core version. for instance, `dotnet new console --version??` How to do that? I don't need to create a project and then to change in `csproj` or `global.json` to a spcific version, but I need that on the command prompt level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it in global.json **is** the way to set the current runtime version in terms of what you are trying to do. Even if there were a way in the command level it should only create a global.json file with the same configuration and then make the new app. The reason I say "should" is because there is already a way to do this, it wouldn't make sense to have a second way.

If updating the global.json file and then creating new projects doesn't work for you, then that is the bug you need to focus on fixing. I wouldn't advise trying to move away from global.josn. I have just tested this out. The generated templates are based on the respective version. If this isn't working, update your question with the exact errors.

Comment: thank you. It worked. **(1)** I created a global.json file in the current directory, then **(2)** run `dotnet new console -n <project_name>`. Previously, I was creating global.json after the project creation. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to control this is by creating a global.json file. When I need to do this, I run `dotnet new globaljson` and then edit the SDK version in the file.

Comment: the issue is that I am getting problems after changing the sdk version in global.json, as the libraries are different as many errors are poped up once the version is changed (try mvc template for example)

Comment: You'll have to ask a new question about those errors since I'm not really sure what errors you are describing. There is no way to tell `dotnet` which version of the SDK to run without using a global.json file.

Comment: global.json is the way to do this. if you had issues when you change the sdk in global.json, then that is your real issue that you will need to focus on solving.

Comment: thanks you both. I know issues need to be solved, this is why I asked this question. I wanted to create the project in the stable expected version strightaway, so no need to deal with preview version issues

Comment: thanks @natemcmaster, but the other answer was more helpful for me. thanks anyway